# How Can I start a Process in JBPM using REST API (for JBPM 7.1.0 only)

Tags: rest, jbpm

I want to start process and do other tasks in JBPM 7.1.0 using REST API. Though these APIs are available for earlier versions of JBPM, but I am not able to implement it in 7.1.0. kindly help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer based on assumption that you have deployed a container in KIE-SERVER.

first of all...

go to 
`{server}:{port}/kie-server/docs/` to get the full documentation.

To start a process: it really depends whether the project you are running is case project (new in jbpm 7) or normal project.

1. for case-project [POST]

   {server}:{port}/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/{containerID}/cases/{processID}/instances
2. for normal process [POST]

   {server}:{port}/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/{containerID}/processes/{processID}/instances

Comment: For the classic employee evaluation process example of jBPM documentation, the HTTP request to create a process instance looks like the following.  "evaluation_1.0" is the process container id and "evaluation" is the process id/name.                                       
` POST /kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/evaluation_1.0/processes/evaluation/instances HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization: Basic {basic auth token}
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 43

{"initiator": "<jbpm user name>", "employee":"<employee name>"}`